# Set and get session values in HttpContext.Current.Session in C#

Tags: c#, session

I have static class called CommoonHelper.

```
 public static  class CommonHelper
    {

        public static SessionObjects sessionObjects
        {
            get
            {

                if ((HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionObjects"] == null))
                {

                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionObjects"] as SessionObjects;
                }
            }
            set {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionObjects"] = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

In SessionObjects Class, I have defined properties for get /set like below.

```
 public class SessionObjects
    {
        public  int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName
        {
            get
            {
              return  FirstName + "" + LastName;
            }
        }
    }
```

When i try to assign an value like below.

```
CommonHelper.sessionObjects.LastName = "test";
```

Its throwing the below exception.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How do i fix this ?

Comment: I don't understand your first `if()` check, if `HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionObjects"] == null` then you will return that same object casted with the `as` operator, but since the left side is null you still return `null`. You need to create a new instance of that object there.

Comment: I'm using static class, then why should new instance needed ?

Comment: But the property `CommonHelper.sessionObjects` will return `null` in the case above. Check that with `var sess = CommonHelper.sessionObjects; if(sess == null) Console.WriteLine("Null reference."); else Console.WriteLine("Got non-null.");`.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is coming null. how can I create an instance and use the instance here.@MaximilianGerhardt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a new instance of the `SessionObjects` class when the `SessionObjects` object of the current instance is `null`.

```
 public static  class CommonHelper
    {    
        public static SessionObjects sessionObjects
        {
            get
            {
                if ((HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionObjects"] == null))
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("sessionObjects", new SessionObjects()); 
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionObjects"] as SessionObjects;
            }
            set { HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionObjects"] = value; }
        }
    }
```